# Make a text box appear on dragging point in highchart or an editable tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, gwt-highcharts

I have implemented a drag-drop highchart. I want to play around the tooltip. I have added a textbox input field in the tooltip,  the textbox appears, but I cannot write anything in the box. Here is a fiddle for my work .....

http://jsfiddle.net/rahul172/7rSmT/1/

```
tooltip: {
    shared: false,
    useHTML: true,
    //headerFormat: '<small>{point.key}</small><table>',
    pointFormat: '<input type="text">',

   // footerFormat: '</table>'
   // yDecimals: 2
},
```

I want to put the text to get feedback from chart.

Comment: Post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable highcharts tooltip, preare your own div (positioned absolute and hidden). Then on mouse over event (on the point) show your custom div.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver

EDIT: jsfiddle.net/7rSmT/5

Comment: Thanks for the response. Although you pointed me towards the right direction, but now there is one issue. The custom tooltip is not where the mouse pointer is. The text box is also working fine. But I can't get the coordinates to set it just above the mouse pointer. Here is the updated fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/rahul172/7rSmT/4/